# Displaying only 2 decimal places using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, decimal

I want to display only 2 decimal places.
Here's my code.

```
$("#nlots, #prlot").keyup(function() {
    $("#quotation").val($("#prlot").val() * $("#nlots").val());
});
```

Comment: use `toFiexed(number_of_decimal_points_you_want)` inbuild property comes with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`Number#toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** method for that

```
$("#nlots, #prlot").keyup(function() {
    $("#quotation").val(($("#prlot").val() * $("#nlots").val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It worked! Thank you. :)